# Include External js file to angular 5.0.0 project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to include [hello.js](https://adodson.com/hello.js/) in my angular 5.0.2 project.

**Below is the cli version**

[image]

I have added the script file to the angular-cli.json file.

```
"scripts": [
        "./js/hello.js",
        "./js/hello.polyfill.js",
       ]
```

The path is correct as i'm also loading style in the angular-cli.json which are loading fine.

In my service file i'm importing hello as below:

```
declare var hello: any;
declare var gapi: any;
```

but when i run ng build the console shows the error:

**Cannot find module 'hello'.**

If i load the files through script tag in the index.html the code and imports works fine .Only when i add it to the angular-cli.json file it stops working.

Please guide 
Thanks

Comment: Why not install the types for hello.js? `npm i -D @types/hellojs`

Comment: what is your folder structure? try putting you js file inside `assets/js` folder and provide path `assets/js/hello.js`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the scripts array in angular-cli.json or angular.json.

You must also specify the assets folder:

```
"scripts": [
        "./assets/js/hello.js",
        "./assets/js/hello.polyfill.js",
       ]
```

Comment: Is this the answer?

Comment: can you post in which file?

Comment: .angular-cli.json

Comment: I mentioned proper path, but still when i tried to import it shows error as cannot find module.

Comment: Please note that angular-cli.json is now angular.json.

Comment: If you want to import it as a module then it should be installed with npm.